# How to retrieve "DocIcon" and "Taxonomy" values of items in subfolders?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve values for "DocIcon" and "Taxonomy" in a single call for items inside subfolders. Currently, I am using the following call to retrieve these values for items in the main list:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields
```

However, this call does not return values for items inside subfolders.

For the items inside subfolders, I have tried using the following call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}/children?expand=listItem
```

This call retrieves the items inside subfolders, but even after I expand for listItem, it does not return values for "DocIcon" and "Taxonomy".

Is there a way to retrieve these values for items inside subfolders? Alternatively, can I modify the first call to retrieve items inside subfolders?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use nested `expand`

```
/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}/children?&expand=listitem(expand=fields)

/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}/children?&expand=listitem(expand=fields(select=docicon,taxonomy))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! But sadly it still doesn't show the values for docIcon and Taxonomy

Comment: @Martigeosys I will check if some settings can cause that I see DocIcon and Taxonomy columns and you don't

Comment: I don't know if this can help but this is all the fields I get using select:
{
"@odata.etag":,
"createdDateTime":,
"eTag":,
"id":,
"lastModifiedDateTime":,
"name":,
"size":,
"webUrl":,
"cTag":,
"commentSettings": {
"commentingDisabled": {
"isDisabled": false
}
},
"createdBy": {
"user": {
"displayName":,
"email":,
"id":
}
},
"lastModifiedBy": {
"user": {
"displayName":,
"email":,
"id":
}
},
"parentReference": {
"driveId":,
"driveType":,
"id":,
"path":,
"sharepointIds": {
"listId":,
"listItemUniqueId":,
"siteId":,
"siteUrl":,
"tenantId":,
"webId":
}
}

Comment: @Martigeosys Not sure if you added all properties in the comment. I don't see listitem property and fields property within listitem

Comment: That's the main problem, that it doesn't appear the fields property. And I am using the same url that you told me to use:

/v1.0/sites/{{SiteId}}/drive/items/{folder-id}/children?&expand=listitem(expand=fields(select=docicon,taxonomy))

I really don't understand why this is happening, I have all the permissions in my app.
Maybe is because the version I am using works different. In the headers I specify this:
Prefer: 'apiversion=2.1'

Comment: Yes, it was the apiversion. I switched to 2.0 and now it appears, weird.